# Schema Mismatch while reading from Postgres and writing to Google BigQuery

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, google-bigquery, spark-streaming, google-cloud-dataproc

I have created a pyspark script to migrate data from my PG DB to Google Bigquery via Dataproc, However I am facing an error while running the log on dataproc

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected type: DecimalType(10,0)

```
Source table schema

                                             Table "public.ml_model_logs"

      Column       |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                    Default                    
-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
 log_id            | numeric(12,0)               |           | not null | nextval('seq_ml_model_logs_log_id'::regclass)
 prediction_date   | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 fk_process_id     | numeric(10,0)               |           |          | 
 record_id         | numeric(20,0)               |           |          | 
 model_output_json | json                        |           |          | 
 predicted_ban     | numeric(1,0)                |           |          | 

Indexes:
    "ml_model_logs_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (log_id)
```

```
Dataframe Schema


 |-- log_id: decimal(12,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- prediction_date: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- fk_process_id: decimal(10,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- record_id: decimal(20,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- model_output_json: string (nullable = true)
 |-- predicted_ban: decimal(1,0) (nullable = true)
```

and

```
Destination Table schema

log_id            NUMERIC   NULLABLE  
prediction_date   DATETIME  NULLABLE    
fk_process_id     NUMERIC   NULLABLE       
record_id         NUMERIC   NULLABLE    
model_output_json    JSON   NULLABLE      
predicted_ban     NUMERIC   NULLABLE
```

What I understood is that there is a datatype mismatch between long and NUMERIC datatypes, so I tries typecasting Attributes of Long to to int,Float,DecimalType, LongType to make it compatible with destination tables NUMERIC datatype, But still the error persists.

Can someone please help with this. Thanks in advance.

Edit : Added Source table schema and updated dataframe schema.

Answer (score 0):

The columns in the `DataFrame` that correspond to `BigQuery's NUMERIC` type should be cast to PySpark's DecimalType with the appropriate precision and scale. I provided an example where columns like `log_id, fk_process_id, record_id,` and `predicted_ban` are cast to `DecimalType(38, 0)` to match BigQuery’s NUMERIC datatype. Try below

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType

# Assuming df is your DataFrame
df = df \
    .withColumn("log_id", df["log_id"].cast(DecimalType(38, 0))) \
    .withColumn("fk_process_id", df["fk_process_id"].cast(DecimalType(38, 0))) \
    .withColumn("record_id", df["record_id"].cast(DecimalType(38, 0))) \
    .withColumn("predicted_ban", df["predicted_ban"].cast(DecimalType(38, 0)))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying,
I tried your suggestion but encountered this error

Error in custom provider, java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected type: DecimalType(38,0)

Comment: Check that the versions of Spark, Hadoop, and any other relevant components in your DataProc environment are compatible with handling DecimalType(38,0). Try using a different data type that is compatible with both PySpark and BigQuery. For instance, casting to a LongType if the precision allows, or using StringType as an intermediate type for the migration. Double-check that the schema defined in PySpark exactly matches the schema expected by BigQuery, including the data types and nullable properties.